# Outputting a var with a colon in it

Tags: javascript

I get a something from my config in my js:

```
<script>var r = {{ Config::get('app::r') }}; console.log(r);</script>
```

The {{}} is laravel, it just echos stuff from php.

The problem is I get an error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

The r in config has a : in it. It is:

```
r => '1:1';
```

How can I deal with outputting the string?

Comment: If you want a string, add some quotes around, as in `var r = "{{code}}"`

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>var r = "{{ Config::get('app::r') }}"; console.log(r);</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `"` in the set of `r` variable and you will get a string.

```
<script>var r = "{{ Config::get('app::r') }}"; console.log(r);</script>
```

You also could specify a `property` and set a object in this property, and get a javascript `object`, for sample:

```
<script>var r = { item: { Config::get('app::r') } }; console.log(r);</script>
```

Comment: Interesting, config is an array with a number of vars, would there be a way to map this to js as an array?